# Methods inside a dictionary are not available to reference self

Tags: python

I'm trying to improve my coding by using dictionaries.

I have one with inputs and one with outputs. The problem is that is seems like I can't reference to a dictionary inside said dictionary.

```
def calculate(x,y):
    return x + y

inputs = dict(
              a = 1,
              b = 2,
              c = 3,
              )

outputs = dict(
               d = calculate(inputs['a'], inputs['b']),
               e = calculate(inputs['a'], outputs['d']),
              )
```

`e`  is creating trouble.`NameError: name 'outputs' is not defined`

Should I use self of some sorts here?

Bonus question:

I have about 30 inputs, and 20 output calculations. Do you recommend another way of solving this than the way I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of points here:

- Check your brackets (e.g. last two lines with `calculate(...)`)
- `outputs` is not defined when accessing it with `outputs['d']` (last line, see javo's answer)
- I don't see the advantage of dicts over variables in this scenario

Long story short:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

d = add(a, b)
e = add(a, d)
```

Comment: Oh, ok. I can live with this. Thank you :)

I want to use dicts because later I will loop through the container and write an output file. 

In total, I might have about 50 variables.

Comment: With 50 variables it's probably a diffrent story. What is it exactly that you're trying? (Maybe you can use lists?)